I can install .NET 8.0.301 (v8.0.6) using dotnet-install.ps1 but I can't install .NET 8.0.300 (v8.0.5) on my Windows 10 Pro machine
I'm using the PowerShell (v.5.1) script from Microsoft (dotnet-install.ps1) and I can install the latest SDK v8.0.6 just running the script without any parameters.
However, when I try to install v8.0.5 I'm getting following error:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website

Other notes

I also tried winget


You can use the -Version switch explicitly:
.\dotnet-install.ps1 -Version 8.0.300


is there a reason i would need both 8.0.5 and 8.0.6 SDKs installed?

@Rod usually - no.
